# Is there a website which will send you an email notification when it is visited?

Tags: web-services, gmail, sendmail

Well, I am not a developer and what I want is to find a already existed website(e.g. mail.com). When I visit the webpage:

***wget 'mail.com/test@gmail.com'***,

the server will send a email(any content is OK) to "test@gmail.com".

Does anyone know such a website/service?

Comment: It would help if you were to clarify what you are trying to achieve. It sounds to me that you are after something that sounds very much like it could be used for SPAM...

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am not finding something for SPAM. The fact is, I am using a remote Linux server for some jobs, and I want to send myself a mail after jobs done, but there is no sendmail like programs in that machine(And I cannot install one). So I would like to use other ways to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that a public website like this could be used for spam, and likely doesn't exist.  But you can easily set up a perl/python/ruby server on your local host that does this.  Check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I've lost every time it comes to something like server/hosts. I am using my own laptop, can that work?

Comment: You definitely can use your own laptop; just run the server on your laptop and point your web browser to localhost or the local ip (usually 127.0.0.1)

Comment: Ok, now I know how to send mail by python, though still not very clear about the python server, thank you.